# CSS - Uniform responsive background images on menu

Tags: css, html-lists, responsive-design

I'm creating a mobile friendly responsive version of a flash website. The problem I'm facing is that each background image on the top menu has a different width, so I'm not being able to set them side by side properly and have a uniform size at the same time, they are getting scaled to fit the container.

This is a list style menu using background images and a hover effect. I'm using background-size:contain.

This is my CSS, which repeats for all items:

```
ul.menu {
   list-style:none;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   right:24px;
   top:-100px;
   margin-bottom:-32px;
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:right;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   float:right;
}

ul.menu li {
   display:inline-block;
   list-style-image:none !important;
   text-align:right;
   width:15%;
   height:100%;
   float:right;
}

li.roca a {
   background: url(../images/roca1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   height:100%;
   -moz-background-size:contain; 
   -webkit-background-size:contain; 
   background-size:contain;
}

li.roca a:hover {
   background: url(../images/roca2.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
   -moz-background-size:contain; 
   -webkit-background-size:contain; 
   background-size:contain;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="roca"><a href="http:..." target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="img2"><a href="http:..." target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="img3"><a href="http:..." target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="img4"><a href="http:..." target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="img5"><a href="http:..." target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone has an idea what code could fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use background images for things that are actually content...in this case the text itself would be better off using a web font and the background image would just be the texture.  If you need an image for some reason you should be using an `img` tag with the proper `alt` text.  If for some reason you really want to fight this you should at least have content in the tags for accessibility.
- Separating the text out from the background image (which is **highly** recommended and there's little reason to not do it with the power of CSS3 font support) would then solve all of the layout issues and if you need a more controlled dynamically sized background image you should use a "sliding door" approach.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I know that's the way to go.